# Using group with Inner Join in Sequelize giving error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to write this raw query

```
SELECT users.status,count(`users`.`id`) AS `count` 
FROM `users` AS `users` 
   INNER JOIN `organization_entries` AS `organizationEntries` ON `users`.`id` = `organizationEntries`.`user_id` 
       AND `organizationEntries`.`organization_id` = '1' 
       AND `organizationEntries`.`type` = '001' 
group by users.status;
```

in Sequelize .

I have written this query in Sequelize like this

```
db.users
    .findAll({
      attributes: [
        'status',
        [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'users.id'), 'entries']
      ],
      include: {
        model: db.organizationEntries,
        where: {


          organization_id: req.params.org_id,
          type: '001',

        },
      },
      group: ['users.status']
    }).then(c => {
      console.log(c);

      let active_users = {
        active_users: c,
      }
      return res.send(active_users);

    })
    .catch(next);
```

but when I am running this query I am getting this error

> code  "ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP" errno   1055 sqlState   "42000"
>
> sqlMessage    "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'ontro.users.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

> If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING
>   condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are
>   neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on
>   them.

Please read on [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).